# Sacar valor input range y imprimirlo en un div

Tags: javascript, entrada

estoy queriendo mostrar unos datos de precio a través de inputs y javaScript.

**Select productos**

```
<select class="form-control corrigForm" name="maquina" id="maquina">
   <option value="0" disabled selected>Seleccione una Maquina...</option>
   <option value="435€">Láser Diode +</option>
   <option value="455€">Láser Dualwave</option>
</select>
```

**Me muestra el precio del producto**

```
<h5 id="MaquinaElegida">0€</h5>
```

**Input donde muestro el valor de Range y el range**

```
<div class="input-group formMarg2">      
  <input type="text" id="precio" class="form-control corrigForm" style="height: calc(2.55rem + 2px);text-align: center;" value="60">
  <div class="input-group-addon">Meses</div>
</div> 

  <input type="range" id="tiempo" class="myRange" name="points" min="36" max="60" value="60" step="12">
```

**Aquí tiene que mostrar lo que os comento más abajo**

```
<h5 id="pvpRoyalty">0€</h5>
```

**Script donde saco el precio del producto y muestro en el input el valor del range**

```
 <script>
  $(document).on('change', '#maquina', function(event) {
    $('#MaquinaElegida').text($("#maquina option:selected").val());
  });
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tiempo').change(function() {
    $('#precio').val($(this).val());
   });
  });
 </script>
```

Entonces lo que necesito es que cuando seleccionen en el range el valor 36 (tiene que salir en el `<h5 id="pvpRoyalty">335€</h5>`, si eligen el valor 48 saldrá `<h5 id="pvpRoyalty">250€</h5>` y por ultimo si el valor es 60 `<h5 id="pvpRoyalty">200€</h5>`. El input range solo tiene esas tres posiciones y ya se imprimen en el input con `id="precio"`.

Eso se puede hacer?, sobre todo que sea sin actualizar como lo que hay hasta ahora. Gracias

Comment: supongo que quieres ver los precios solo informativo, si los calculas del lado del cliente corres el riesgo de que algun aficionado o  incluso algun experto de informatica cambie los valores a su voluntad

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, de momento este módulo lo dejamos parado, porque es posible que lo utilicemos para otra cosa, gracias!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale aun no tengo muy claro aun que es lo que quieres lograr en cuanto a la suma de tus inputs, para dejar esto a un lado tal vez deberías repasar [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Pero sin embargo para responder a tu pregunta final, propongo que apliques la siguiente lógica.

Si tienes una serie de valores a los cuales deseas que signifiquen varios valores al mismo tiempo, valga la redundancia y los quieres imprimir en la pagina (ambos), ya sea como en un carro de compras o un checkout. Trabaja con varibles y crea un sistema de casos en los cuales si el valor que retorna es equis numero, esta nueva variable tiene ahora otro valor (mírese en el ejemplo de abajo).

> **NOTA**: Mejor utiliza valores enteros en vez de un string para colocar los precios ya que así los puedes sumar mas adelante, el signo de la moneda puede ser estático como en el ejemplo.

En cuanto al introducir en la etiqueta que necesites el valor del slide que presentas, te recomendaría que uses `bind()` u `on()` en lugar de `change()` y los trabajes en una sola variable ya que es el valor final.

> Mira el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  /*Aqui cambio el input de las maquinas en la etiqueta h5*/
  
  $("#maquina").on("change", function(e){
  
    $("#precio span").html($(this).val())
  
  });
  
  /*-----------AQUI LOS CAMBIOS DE INTERES-----------*/
  
  $("#tiempo").on("input change", function(){
  
    var pvp; 
    var thisval = $(this).val();
  
    $("#tempsnap span").html(thisval);
    
    /*-----------SISTEMA DE CASOS (CON IF/ELSE)-----------*/
    
    if (thisval == 60) {
    
      pvp = 200;
      $("#pvpRoyalty span").html(pvp); //Imprimo la varible pvp en el span.
    
    }else if (thisval == 48) {
    
      pvp = 250;
      $("#pvpRoyalty span").html(pvp); // !!!
    
    }else if (thisval == 36) {
    
      pvp = 335;
      $("#pvpRoyalty span").html(pvp); // !!!
    
    }
  
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control corrigForm" name="maquina" id="maquina">
   <option value="0" disabled selected>Seleccione una Maquina...</option>
   <option value="435">Láser Diode +</option>
   <option value="455">Láser Dualwave</option>
</select>

<h5 id="precio">Precio: <span>0</span>€</h5>

<h5 id="tempsnap">Tiempo: <span>60</span> meses.</h5>

<h5 id="pvpRoyalty"><span>200</span>€</h5>

<input type="range" id="tiempo" class="myRange" name="points" min="36" max="60" value="60" step="12">
```

Espero te sirva, un saludo.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda, de momento dejamos parado este módulo pero he comprobado tu solución y funciona perfectamente, la dejo marcada como la respuesta buena!

Answer (score 0):

Si te he entendido bien, puedes solucionarlo con un simple `switch` del valor del `range`:

```
switch($(this).val()) {
    case "36":
        $('#pvpRoyalty').val("335€");
        $('#pvpRoyalty').html("335€");
        break;
    case "48":
        $('#pvpRoyalty').val("250€");
        $('#pvpRoyalty').html("250€");
        break;
    case "60":
        $('#pvpRoyalty').val("200€");
        $('#pvpRoyalty').html("200€");
        break;
    default:
        $('#pvpRoyalty').val("0€");
}
```

Te dejo [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/tzo5cqgy/) un fiddle

**Nota**: No entiendo muy bien qué quieres multiplicar (lo digo por el título de tu pregunta)

Comment: Tienes razón con el titulo, iba pensando otra cosa y se me fue la cabeza, utilice lo que me pasaste pero me devuelve un error de javascript @Kiko_L

Comment: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at n.fn.init.val (VM23601 jquery.min.js:4)
    at franquicias.php:387

Comment: Eso parece otro problema no relacionado con esto (tiene toda la pinta de ser algún problema de orden de carga de scripts)

Comment: Intenta colocar tus scripts en el siguiente orden: JQuery en primer lugar, Plugins y pequeños scripts secundarios en segundo lugar y tu script principal al final, mejor si es bajo la etiqueta `<body>`.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, de momento este módulo lo dejamos parado, porque es posible que lo utilicemos para otra cosa, gracias!!!